# Collada (.dae) file with line element on autodesk-viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I uploaded few collada (.dae) file to autodesk-viewer api and found no issues in model with 2D elements like polygon. But same will not work for file with line (1D) elements.

This is the file I'm uploading to autodesk-viewer.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApS9nIpyJIuQa7JD9cl3CI5WPk0

Comment: This question relies on a link that is dead, so the question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The translation of .dae files or any file in general to a svf format only supports 2D and 3D formats.

Read https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#svf-output

Comment: But are these specification not for the viewer ? How can all 1D elements like lines can be ignored in translation. Can you give me more information on this please.

Comment: So lines are 2D elements, points are 1D elements, Let me ask about those, I know lines with a DWG work fine, but let me get back to you ok.